# Can xchg instruction insure memory ordering?

Tags: operating-system, x86, cpu

Some os kernels use `xchg` instruction to implement the `spinlock`. And inside their implementation of acquire lock function, they usually disable interrupts before acquiring the lock using `xchg` instruction. So, can `xchg` instruction insure memory ordering? I mean can `xchg` instruction insure that disable interrupts will not be called after it?

Answer (score 1):

No XCHG instruction can't do that.
At the XCHG instruction execution, the processor's LOCK signal is automatically asserted so we don't need the extra LOCK prefix to ensure that instruction is preformed atomically.
The XCHG is always performed atomically! And there is no need to disable interrupts.

Comment: The XCHG is always performed atomically. but only when an operand is memory, lock signal is implicit. of course, when all operands are register, no need of lock signal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. XCHG instruction can do that.

I get a better answer on [why can MemoryBarrier be implemented as a call to xchg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652824/why-can-memorybarrier-be-implemented-as-a-call-to-xchg).