# Exit critical region

Tags: multithreading, x86, locking, x86-64, mutual-exclusion

Consider several threads executing concurrently the following code:

```
long gf = 0;// global variable or class member

//...

if (InterlockedCompareExchange(&gf, 1, 0)==0) // lock cmpxchg
{
    // some exclusive code - must not execute in concurrent
    gf = 0; // this is ok ? or need
    //InterlockedExchange(&gf, 0); // [lock] xchg 
}
```

Treat the code above as C-like pseudo-code, which will be translated more-or-less directly into assembly without the usual concessions to compiler optimizations such as re-odering and store elimination.

So after some thread exclusively acquires flag `gf`- to exit from the critical region is it enough to write a zero (as in `gf = 0`) or does this need to be interlocked - `InterlockedExchange(&gf, 0)`?

If both are OK, which is better from a performance view, assuming that with high probability that several cores concurrently call `InterlockedCompareExchange(&gf, 1, 0)`?

Several threads periodically execute this code (from several places, when some events fire) and it is important that the next thread again enters the critical region as soon as possible after it freed.

Comment: I'd use a more detailed title and add a couple tags here, you'll get some more help.

Comment: @Ryanman - this question (how i view) related only to x86-x64 memory order. not related to compiler, language, os. so not view which more tag can be used here or more details

Comment: It is definitely related to la language and compiler as Peter's answer shows. As pseodo-code without a re-oredring compiler it works, as actual C or C++ with a specific memory model it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related: [Spinlock with XCHG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731166/spinlock-with-xchg) explains why you *don't* need `xchg` to release a lock in x86 asm, just a store instruction.

**But *in C++*, you need something stronger than a plain `gf = 0;` on a plain `long gf` variable.**  The C / C++ memory model (for normal variables) is very weakly ordered, even when compiling for strongly-ordered x86, because that's essential for optimizations.

**You need a release-store to correctly release a lock**, without allowing operations in the critical section to leak out of the critical section by reordering at compile time or runtime with the `gf=0` store.  http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/.

Since you're using `long gf`, not `volatile long gf`, and you aren't using a compiler memory barrier, nothing in your code would prevent compile-time reordering.  (x86 asm stores have release semantics, so it's only compile-time reordering we need to worry about.)  http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/

---

**We get everything we need as cheaply as possible using `std::atomic<long> gf;` and `gf.store(0, std::memory_order_release);`**  `atomic<long>` is lock-free on every platform that supports `InterlockedExchange`, AFAIK, so you should be ok to mix and match.  (Or just use `gf.exchange()` to take the lock.  If rolling your own locks, keep in mind that you should loop on a read-only operation + `_mm_pause()` while waiting for the lock, don't hammer away with `xchg` or `lock cmpxchg` and potentially delay the unlock.  See [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241553/locks-around-memory-manipulation-via-inline-assembly/37246263#37246263).

This is one of the cases where the warning in [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86) that you need `atomic<>` to make sure the compiler actually does the store where / when you need it applies.

Answer (score -1):

`gf = 0` is sufficient. There’s no need to use a locked operation since no other thread can be changing its value.

By the way, I’d use bts instead of cmpxchg to acquire the lock. I’m not sure if it makes any difference in performance, but it’s simpler.

Comment: actually i use `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` to save some pointer value in pointer (register) size variable. at once use this as critical region acquire and data store, which processed in region and release(set to 0) on the exit. not a single bit (0/1). but that does not change the essence

Comment: `lock bts` might be slower, although maybe not with an immediate operand.  (non-locked `bts` sucks with a memory operand, especial with `mem,reg` rather than `mem,imm`, because of the crazy-CISC bitstring indexing).  `xchg mem,reg` is probably best, and it's cheap to test the reg result, like [in my example asm implementation](//stackoverflow.com/a/37246263)  But either way you want to check that the lock is available read-only before using a locked op on that cache line, and then it very often succeed; don't spin on just `lock cmpxchg`, `lock bts`, or `xchg`

Comment: `mov [gf], 0` is sufficient in asm, but `gf = 0` in C / C++ isn't because of compile-time reordering.  http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/

Comment: *`mov [gf], 0` is sufficient in asm* - this is main for me here. i know about possible C/C++ compiler reordering and this is not a problem for me here - before and after `gf = 0` exist external api calls - any compiler not reorder this operations, because this break program logic