# How compare_exchange C++ function determines race conditions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86-64, atomic, compare-and-swap

As we know, `compare_exchange_weak()` returns an error (false value) if there's a race condition, so the operation can not be fully done. But how exactly race condition is determined by `compare_exchange_weak()`?

Does `lock cmpxchg` instruction returns an error if more that one thread tries to read/write value, i.e. acquire a lock and exactly this way `compare_exchange_weak` determines race condition?

Comment: Are you aware of this Q/A [SO: Understanding std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak() in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25199838/7478597)?

Comment: @Scheff Thanks, I have read this Q/A and have found a lot of useful info, but I still didn't find an answer. I just want to know, how exactly is race condition detected by compare_exchange_ function

Comment: I've googled "compare_exchange_weak() lock cmpxchg". I'm under the impression that concerning Intel x86/x64, all these subtle details of locking, considered in C++11, are not so relevant as Intel commands are not that diverse. I couldn't find something which I would link as "proof" but you may search yourself to "get a feeling".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that on x86 `compare_exchange_weak` does the same as `compare_exchange_strong`. `cmpxchg` instruction sets ZF (zero flag), depending on whether value was equal and consequently was changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cmpxchg` instruction affects the `ZF` flag: it is set if the exchange succeeded and it is cleared otherwise.

Let's see this with an example:

```
std::atomic<int> a;

bool my_compare_exchange(int expected, int desired) {
   bool succeeded = a.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired);
   return succeeded;
}
```

The function `my_compare_exchange()` is translated into the following assembly code:

```
my_compare_exchange:
        mov     eax, edi
        lock cmpxchg    DWORD PTR a[rip], esi
        sete    al // <-- conditional instruction
        ret
```

The register `al` is set to `1` using `sete al` if the exchange succeeded (i.e., `ZF` was set by `cmpxchg`). Otherwise, it is set to zero (i.e., `ZF` was cleared by `cmpxchg`).

Comment: thanks, now I got how compare_exchange detects race condition. But i also have 2 new questions :)

Comment: First, ```lock``` prefix does next instruction being executed atomically, so the ```cmpxchg``` will execute correctly, but there's also ```sete al``` instruction, why it is not being executed atomically? What if tho threads tries to set value to ```al``` register

Comment: No, `al` does not interfere, since each thread has its own `al` register (`al` is not shared between threads). The same applies for the stack.

Comment: The only atomic instruction is the `lock cmpxchg`.

Comment: And the second question: i tried to disassembly your code and see this instruction: ```test    al, al```. Why we need this instruction? Is it not enough to just set ```al``` register?

Comment: `test al, al` is probably for checking whether `al` is zero (Is it followed by `jz` / `jnz` ?). Try to enable the optimizations with `-O2`.

Comment: Oops, i turned it on now and see exactly the same assembly code as yours, thanks! I accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

`lock cmpxchg` is atomic; nothing can happen during its execution (logically anyway).  Unlike an LL/SC implementation of `compare_exchange_weak`, it can't spuriously fail when another thread is writing inside the same cache line, only if the compare actually fails.  ([Can CAS fail for all threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268929/can-cas-fail-for-all-threads))

`compare_exchange_strong` can be implemented as `lock cmpxchg` without requiring a loop.

---

Are you asking about the use-case where you load the old value, modify it, and then try to CAS a new value into place?  (e.g. to synthesize an atomic operation that the hardware doesn't provide directly, e.g. [atomic FP add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055402/atomic-double-floating-point-or-sse-avx-vector-load-store-on-x86-64), or [atomic clear-lowest-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346815/atomically-clearing-lowest-non-zero-bit-of-an-unsigned-integer)).

In that case yes, the reason for `cmpxchg` failure would be a race with another thread.

As @ネロク explained, you check the flag result of `cmpxchg` to get the boolean result of `compare_exchange_strong`, i.e. to tell whether the compare part failed and whether the store was done or not.  See [Intel's manual entry for `cmpxchg`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG.html).

---

There are other use-cases for `lock cmpxchg` too, like waiting for a spinlock to become available by spinning on `lock.compare_exchange_weak(0, 1)`, repeatedly trying to CAS an unlocked variable into a locked state.  So a failed CAS isn't from a race condition, it's simply from the lock still being held.  (Because you're passing a constant as the "expected", not what you just read from that location.)

This is generally not a good idea, AFAIK.  I think it's normally better to spin read-only waiting for a lock, and only try to take the lock with a CAS or an XCHG if you saw it was available.  (Using `xchg` and testing the integer result is potentially cheaper than `lock cmpxchg`, possibly keeping the cache line locked for fewer cycles.  [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241553/locks-around-memory-manipulation-via-inline-assembly/37246263#37246263))

---

TL:DR: lockless programming requires precision language if you're going to reason about correctness.

`cmpxchg` fails and clears ZF (creating the `ne` not-equal condition) if EAX doesn't match the value in memory when it executes.  The instruction itself doesn't know or care about races, just the exact state when it itself executes.

You as a programmer have to worry about races and retrying when using it as a building block to create larger atomic operations built on top of it.