# Is Interlock.CompareExchange atomic inside an if statement?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, compare-and-swap, interlocked

I am assuming that the piece of code is threadsafe,

```
if ((Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref semaphore, 1, 0) == 0))
{
  //Do Stuff
  semaphore = 0;
}
```

However I am wondering why:

In my mind I see this as two operations,

1. First it compares the semaphore with the value, and replaces it if they are equal
   `(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref semaphore, 1, 0)`
2. Then it compares the value it returns to 0, with the stamement `{CompareExchange} == 0`

Can not the semaphore bet set somewhere else, before the second comparison (2.) happens? And that the function gets entered when it should not?

Comment: You're setting `semaphore` in the `if`, which doesn't really seem to make sense: it's already being set (in a thread-safe way) by the `CompareExchange`.

Comment: The whole point of the return value from `CompareExchange` is it returns the previous value as it was at the time of the exchange - information you could not obtain by re-reading the variable yourself because, as you say, it might have been changed in the meantime.

Comment: What is the intention of your code? Is it to provent concurrent executions of the `//Do Stuff` by more than one threads? In that case check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75728657/is-it-safe-to-use-the-interlocked-compareexchange-as-a-lock-only-for-enter-not "Is it safe to use the Interlocked.CompareExchange as a lock, only for enter, not for exit?") recent question.

Comment: "*Can not the semaphore bet set somewhere else,...*" -- The meaning of this phrase is obscure to me. Is the "bet" a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Interlocked.CompareExchange` is an atomic operation, resulting in a return value.  Once that happens, the result of that method call cannot change unless you call `Interlocked.CompareExchange` again, even if `semaphore` changes.  It doesn't matter that it is inside an `if` statement; you can depend on that return value to be stable.