# Two Different Processes With 2 std::atomic Variables on Same Address?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-memory, stdatomic

I read C++ Standard (n4713)'s § 32.6.1 3:

> Operations that are lock-free should also be address-free. That is,
>   atomic operations on the same memory location via two different
>   addresses will communicate atomically. The implementation should not
>   depend on any per-process state. This restriction enables
>   communication by memory that is mapped into a process more than once
>   and by memory that is shared between two processes.

So it sounds like it is possible to perform a lock-free atomic operation on the same memory location.  I wonder how it can be done.

Let's say I have a named shared memory segment on Linux (via shm_open() and mmap()).  How can I perform a lockfree operation on the first 4 bytes of the shared memory segment for example?

At first, I thought I could just `reinterpret_cast` the pointer to `std::atomic<int32_t>*`.  But then I read [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4013.html).  It first points out that std::atomic might not have the same size of T or alignment:

> When we designed the C++11 atomics, I was under the misimpression that
>   it would be possible  to semi-portably apply atomic operations to data
>   not declared to be atomic, using  code such as

```
int x; reinterpret_cast<atomic<int>&>(x).fetch_add(1);
```

> This would clearly fail if the representations of atomic and int
>   differ, or if their alignments differ. But I know that this is not an
>   issue on platforms I care about. And, in practice, I can easily test
>   for a problem by checking at compile time that sizes and alignments
>   match.

Tho, it is fine with me in this case because I use a shared memory on the same machine and casting the pointer in two different processes will "acquire" the same location.  However, the article states that the compiler might not treat the casted pointer as a pointer to an atomic type:

> However this is not guaranteed to be reliable, even on platforms on
>   which one  might expect it to work, since it may confuse type-based
>   alias analysis in the  compiler. A compiler may assume that an int is
>   not also accessed as an `atomic<int>`. (See 3.10, [Basic.lval], last
>   paragraph.)

Any input is welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't concern itself with multiple processes and no guarantees were given outside of a multi-threaded environment.
However, the standard does [recommend](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/atomics#lockfree-5) that implementations of lock-free atomics be usable across processes, which is the case in most real implementations.
This answer will assume atomics behave more or less the same with processes as with threads.

The first solution requires C++20 [`atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref)

```
void* shared_mem = /* something */

auto p1 = new (shared_mem) int;  // For creating the shared object
auto p2 = (int*)shared_mem;      // For getting the shared object

std::atomic_ref<int> i{p2};      // Use i as if atomic<int>
```

You need to make sure the shared `int` has `std::atomic_ref<int>::required_alignment` alignment; typically the same as `sizeof(int)`.  Normally you'd use `alignas()` on a struct member or variable, but in shared memory the layout is up to you (relative to a known page boundary).

This prevents the presence of opaque atomic types existing in the shared memory, which gives you precise control over what exactly goes in there.

---

A solution prior C++20 would be

```
auto p1 = new (shared_mem) atomic<int>;  // For creating the shared object
auto p2 = (atomic<int>*)shared_mem;      // For getting the shared object

auto& i = *p2;
```

Or using C11 [`atomic_load`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_load) and [`atomic_store`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_store)

```
_Atomic int* i = (_Atomic int*)shared_mem;
atomic_store(i, 42);
int i2 = atomic_load(i);
```

Alignment requirements are the same here, `alignof(std::atomic<int>)` or `_Alignof(atomic_int)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Your pre-C++20 solution casts the shared memory to `std::atomic<int>`.  [This article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4013.html) suggests that casting to `std::atomic<int>` (or `std::atomic<int>*`) might be invalid/confuse the compiler.  Thought?

Comment: @HCSF There is no casting between regular and atomic types here, I only retrieved a pointer to a previously constructed atomic object.

Comment: @PasserBy Nice post. We seem to have two `p`s (in a POD?, lol).

Comment: @PaulSanders The sample code is for exposition only, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @PasserBy Sure, but it should at least compile :)  Why don't you fix it? I found it confusing, and others may do too.

Comment: @PasserBy Ah! I see you comments now.  So the first line is using the placement new for creating the shared object on the mapped shared memory and the 2nd is for getting the created shared object on the mapped shared memory.  Now, I just wonder whether the memory orders are still working as defined in the standard if we start calling `store()`/`load()` on `p`.

Comment: @HCSF Sure they are.  Why would they not be?

Comment: I mean process A calls `p->store(x, std::memory_order_release)` and process B calls `p->load(std::memory_order_acquire)` (for example), then all the writes from process A prior to storing x will be visible to process B when process B calls load() (as defined in the standard)?  The reason I have doubt is as you also stated in your 2nd sentence -- This answer will assume the program behaves more or less the same with processes as with threads in regards to synchronization.

Comment: @HCSF I think it reasonable to assume that, considering the factors contributing to data races, but when in doubt always check on your particular platform.

Comment: No offense -- I just wonder what the best way to check/test.  Just want to be very sure.  I am on x86-64 (or Skylake to be precise).

Comment: @HCSF Look into their [manuals](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf)

Comment: That's a very thick one.  I just tried to do something very [simple](https://godbolt.org/g/GWZdrM).  The machine codes are very simple -- mainly 2 `mov`.  Now, I wonder how the effect of `std::memory_order_release` and `std::memory_order_acquire` occurs -- all writes prior to release will appear when acquire successfully reads.  I looked at the `mov` section in the manual.  It doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: hmm...it is off topic.  I will ask in another post.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the C++ standard is a bit mealy-mouthed about all this.

If you are on Windows (which you probably aren't) then you can use [`InterlockedExchange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-interlockedexchange) etc, which offer all the required semantics and don't care where the referenced object is (it's a LONG *).

On other platforms, gcc has some [atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) which might help with this.  They might free you from the tyranny of the standards writers.  Trouble is, it's hard to test if the resulting code is bullet-proof.

Comment: Yes testing is the issue.  That's why I turned to c++ standard and hope to get bullet proof there.

Comment: [Inspect the code generated by the compiler](http://www.godbolt.org).  If it uses the `XCHG` instruction then you're safe as this offers both atomicity and a memory fence at the hardware level.

Comment: Right, gcc's builtin should work.  In fact, my code is using gcc's builtins.  Just that the speed is deteriorated on Skylake (by like 40% slower comparing to i7, Ivy, etc).  I narrowed down to `__sync_sychronize()`.  `__sync_sychronize()` is translated to `mfence` on x86_64, and nothing else.  With `std::atomic`'s operations, surprisingly I don't see any fence, and so I hope to use `std::atomic` but because of the unclear behavior of using `std::atomic` across processes, I am hesitated to use without confirming its behavior.  That's why this post occurred :)

Comment: OK.  You don't need that `mfence` with `xchg` (which is what `std::atomic` uses, IIRC), because `xchg` takes care of that for you.  But @PasserBy is offering good advice, I would take it.  Using placement `new` is actually a very neat solution and I'd be perfectly happy to use that in my own code.  Upvoted.  My answer is not really all that relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I use mfence for another purpose.  Tho, it can be swapped with xchg as you suggested to get full barrier on x86-64.  I will give it a try (the `lock` prefix in the instruction doesn't seem very friendly).  Yes, Passer's answer is good enough I think.  Will accept his answer.

Comment: OK.  Not sure what you mean by `x86-64` but just for clarity / pedantry `XCHG` works equally well in 32 bit or 64 bit apps.  You don't need `lock` with `xchg` - you get that for free.  Overall, it's the simplest and cheapest way to implement `std:;atomic_int` at the assembler level, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652824/why-can-memorybarrier-be-implemented-as-a-call-to-xchg.

Answer (score 1):

On all mainstream platforms, `std::atomic<T>` does have the same size as `T`, although possibly higher alignment requirement if `T` has alignof < sizeof.

You can check these assumptions with:

```
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(std::atomic<T>), 
            "atomic<T> isn't the same size as T");

  static_assert(std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free,  // C++17
            "atomic<T> isn't lock-free, unusable on shared mem");

  auto atomic_ptr = static_cast<atomic<int>*>(some_ptr);
           // beware strict-aliasing violations
           // don't also access the same memory via int*
           // unless you're aware of possible issues
      // also make sure that the ptr is aligned to alignof(atomic<T>)
      // otherwise you might get tearing (non-atomicity)
```

On exotic C++ implementations where these aren't true, people that want to use your code on shared memory will need to do something else.

Or if *all* accesses to shared memory from all processes consistently use `atomic<T>` then there's no problem, you only need lock-free to guarantee address-free.  (You do need to check this: std::atomic uses a hash table of locks for non-lock-free.  This is address-dependent, and separate processes will have separate hash tables of locks.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I think `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` assumes the atomic object will be aligned right?

Comment: Do you think Passer By's C++11 solution using `volatile` and `atomic_store/load()` (I think `atomic_store/load_explicit` variants are even better as they give finer control on memory ordering) is better than casting to `atomic<int>*`?  Because the atomic functions will take care of size and alignment ?

Comment: @HCSF: Yes, `atomic<T>`  only works if you satisfy its `alignof(atomic<T>)` requirement.  Current implementations don't check alignment at runtime to see on a per-instance basis whether it can be lock-free so the `is_lock_free()` member function can just return `is_always_lock_free`.  Misaligned types are UB; the practical result for misaligned `atomic<T>` on x86 is potentially non atomicity (tearing) for pure-load and pure-store, and extreme performance penalties for atomic RMW (check the split lock perf counters).

Comment: @HCSF: PasserBy's C11 solution doesn't need `volatile int*`; that's pointless and wrong.  It should be `atomic_int *p` because that's what you have to pass to `atomic_load`.  `volatile int*p` doesn't implicitly convert to `_Atomic int *` even in C.  But yes, the `_explicit` versions are what you want for passing a memory_order parameter in C.  C++ has function overloads so you can use `p->load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` .  But no, atomic functions don't take care of size and alignment, you need to pass them an aligned pointer of the right type.

Comment: I just looked at the standard again.  `atomic_load/store()` and their `_explicit` variants actually don't take `volatile int*` but `volatile atomic<T>*` and `atomic<T>*` only (shared_ptr<T>* is deprecated).  I was hoping `atomic_load/store_explicit()` would detect alignment and impose lock if misaligned.  Thanks.

Comment: @HCSF: no, that's not remotely close to how anything works.  You really do not want misaligned atomics or runtime alignment detection.  Cache-line-split `lock`-prefixed instructions are so slow there's a performance counter event just to detect them on Intel CPUs.  See [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36624881) for Intel/AMD alignment reqs.  And BTW, the `atomic_load/store` functions only take `volatile atomic<T>*` so they can work for both volatile and non-volatile pointers.  You normally don't use `volatile atomic<T>`.